# Accessing StorageVolumes as system app

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-source

I'm writing an app that explores the file and folder structure of storage volumes attached to an AOSP device. The app is located in the `/system/priv-app` directory on the system image already. A very simplified version of the code is doing the following:

```
StorageManager storageManager = (StorageManager) getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);
List<StorageVolume> volumeList = storageManager.getStorageVolumes();
for (StorageVolume volume : volumeList) {
    Intent accessIntent = volume.createAccessIntent(volume.isPrimary() ? Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC : null);
    startActivityForResult(accessIntent, 42);
}
```

The result is that the user is asked every time to grant permission to access the volume, like in the following screenshot:

[image]

Since the app is system app already, I'd expect the permission to be simply granted. How can I get rid of these access grant requests?

Comment: Post manifest file (request permission) and Android.mk

Comment: Well, any app can list the storage volumes and request permission to access it via volume.createAccessIntent and startActivityForResult.

As I understand it, the question is primarily about if (and if yes: how?) a privileged/system app can bypass the question to the user and gain access to the storage volume directly.

Comment: Asked differently: For which permission exactly would you expect a request in AndroidManifest.xml?